# Time period covered by Network tab of Activity Monitor

Tags: network

I am monitoring my network usage with Activity Monitor. This screenshot shows 1.22 GB of data received and 700 MB data sent at the bottom right:

[image: Network tab of Activity Monitor]

I am having difficulty interpreting these numbers. In the image, I sorted the apps down by "Received bytes" with a total around 443 MB, unlike the total number of 1.22 GB received. That's a discrepancy of 800 MB.

This discrepancy could be explained if the totals refer to the time period since start-up and the app numbers for the time period since launching the app. But I was unable to confirm that as well. [This page](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/5030884) suggests that the total numbers at the bottom right start with computer start-up:

> This however, does reset each time you restart your computer.

while [this thread](https://superuser.com/questions/1191161/output-of-nettop-command) says that they reset when I launch the Activity Monitor:

> the Network tab in Activity Monitor behaves in the same way (totals are from when it starts, not the application being observed)

Do the total and app numbers refer to the time period since the computer turned on or since I launched Activity Monitor? If they are the same, what accounts for the discrepancy of 800 MB in data received?